# "Cannot reference a type through an expression" when using an enum value

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums, webforms

I am receiving an error `cannot reference a type through an expression` when trying to setup my user control initialization through my html markup. I might be shooting for something that I can't even achieve here, but the only help I have been able to find is relating to video games and MVC, of which this is neither.

Basically, I am wanting to initialize a user control value, of type enum, through the markup itself in html. So when you declare the user control it sets all the values needed. Seems to just throw that error though, any insights?

### The Markup

```
<uc:ucStateDropDownList id="UserControls_ucStateDropDownList" runat="server" StatesDisplayed="All"/>
```

### The Code Behind

```
public partial class UserControls_ucStateDropDownList : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private StatesDisplayedInControl m_statesToDisplay;
    /// <summary>
    /// Existing options are as follows:
    ///     - UnitedStates (US states only)
    ///     - Canada (CDN states only)
    ///     - All (All states available)
    /// Default setting is 'All'.   
    /// </summary>
    [Browsable(true)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public StatesDisplayedInControl StatesDisplayed 
    {
        get { return m_statesToDisplay; }
        set { m_statesToDisplay = value; }
    }
    public enum StatesDisplayedInControl : int
    {
        UnitedStates = 0,
        Canada = 1,
        All = 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks correct, off-hand.  Is your enum declared inside or outside the class?  That's the only difference I see from a similar search result I found:  http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?478147-How-to-create-a-custom-property-in-User-Control-of-enum-type-in-C&s=e3476433323a9af7c6dbaee82665ba51&p=1847460#post1847460

Comment: @MikeGuthrie It's inside the class, I updated the code to show.

Comment: @MikeGuthrie Post as the answer and I will accept! Bloody freakin' genius my friend! I'm good to go now, that's all it was.

Comment: I was hesitant to post as answer, since it seems an easy fix.  However, it's an easy problem to encounter, and the message is plain confusing.  Really surprised that I couldn't find any similar question here or all of Google.  Now this question does show up, however, and has an answer for anyone else running into the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that ASP.NET doesn't recognize enum when defined as part of the class. Simply define it in its own file, or rearrange as below, to get this working:

```
public partial class UserControls_ucStateDropDownList : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private StatesDisplayedInControl m_statesToDisplay;
    /// <summary>
    /// Existing options are as follows:
    ///     - UnitedStates (US states only)
    ///     - Canada (CDN states only)
    ///     - All (All states available)
    /// Default setting is 'All'.   
    /// </summary>
    [Browsable(true)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public StatesDisplayedInControl StatesDisplayed 
    {
        get { return m_statesToDisplay; }
        set { m_statesToDisplay = value; }
    }
}

public enum StatesDisplayedInControl : int
{
    UnitedStates = 0,
    Canada = 1,
    All = 2
}
```